# Additional Information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have been working on this for ever it feels like, is there anyone that knows where the dang syntax error is? Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Dim newData As Boolean


    Private Sub TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CustInfo)

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CustInfo.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        showData()

        newData = True


    End Sub


    Sub showData()
        connDB()
        Dim dA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Spouse Name, Phone Number, Address, Application Status, Broker Assigned, Broker Contact, FROM table", conn)
        Dim dS As DataSet = New DataSet
        dS.Clear()
        dA.Fill(dS, "table")
        TableDataGridView.DataSource = dS
        TableDataGridView.DataMember = "table"
        TableDataGridView.Enabled = True
        dA.Dispose()
        conn.Close()


    End Sub

    Private Sub fillTextbox(ByVal x As Integer)
        Try
            Cust_IDTextBox = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
            Customer_NameTextBox = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
            Spouse_NameTextBox = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
            Phone_NumberTextBox = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
            AddressTextBox = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
            Application_StatusTextBox = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value
            Broker_AssignedLabel2 = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value
            Broker_ContactLabel2 = TableDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub TableDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles TableDataGridView.CellContentClick
        fillTextbox(e.RowIndex)
        newData = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Cust_IDTextBox.Text = ""
        Customer_NameTextBox.Text = ""
        Spouse_NameTextBox.Text = ""
        Phone_NumberTextBox.Text = ""
        AddressTextBox.Text = ""
        Phone_NumberTextBox.Text = ""
        Application_StatusTextBox.Text = ""
        Broker_AssignedLabel2.Text = ""
        Broker_ContactLabel2.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim save As String
        Dim message As String
        If Cust_IDTextBox.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
        If newData Then
            message = MsgBox("save", vbYesNo, vbInformation)
            If message = vbYesNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If


            save = "INSERT INTO TABLE(Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Spouse Name, Phone Number, Address, Application Status, Broker Assigned, Broker Contact) VALUES('" & Cust_IDTextBox.Text & "', '" & Customer_NameTextBox.Text & "', '" & Spouse_NameTextBox.Text & "','" & Phone_NumberTextBox.Text & "', '" & AddressTextBox.Text & "', '" & Application_StatusTextBox.Text & "', '" & Broker_AssignedLabel2.Text & "', '" & Broker_ContactLabel2.Text & "')"

        Else
            message = MsgBox("update?", vbYesNo, vbInformation)
            If message = vbYesNo Then Exit Sub

            save = "UPDATE table SET Cust_Name='" & Customer_NameTextBox.Text & "', Spouse Name='" & Spouse_NameTextBox.Text & "', Address='" & AddressTextBox.Text & "', Application Status='" & Application_StatusTextBox.Text & "', Broker Assgined='" & Broker_AssignedLabel2.Text & "', Broker Contact='" & Broker_ContactLabel2.Text & "' WHERE Cust_ID='" & Cust_IDTextBox.Text & "'"

        End If

        runSql(save)
        showData()


    End Sub

    Private Sub runSql(ByVal SQL As String)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        connDB()
        Try
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = SQL
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("done")

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim deleteData As String
        Dim message As String
        message = MsgBox("do you want to delete?", vbYesNo)
        If message = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        deleteData = "DELETE FROM table WHERE cust_id='" & Cust_IDTextBox.Text & "'"
        runSql(deleteData)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

thanks for kindness and help!

Comment: all those column names with spaces in them need to be escaped (or changed so that you dont have to wrestle with it forever).

Comment: Apart from the spaces, you have an extra comma between the last column name and the `FROM` keyword.

Comment: OT, why do you have a typed DataSet and are also using your own ADO.NET code? Use one or the other, not both. If you have a typed DataSet then use it and its associated table adapters and DO NOT use data adapters and vanilla DataSets or DataTables. If you want to write your own ADO.NET code then get rid of the typed DataSet.